# Microsoft OneNote Tool

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

So, usually the OneNote Tool will pop up with a window to ask which notebook to send it to. I accidentally checked the option to always open in a certain notebook. I wan't to clear this because I use the screen clipping thing for all my notebooks. Is there a way to reset this? I am using OneNote 2013 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

In OneNote, go to the File tab -> Options -> Send to OneNote (tab on the left). You change these dropdowns so that content goes to a particular notebook or you can reset it so that it asks you every time.

[image]